# Differing outputs depending on where one is accessing a page from?

Tags: php, browser, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm having a weird problem regarding PHP and **charset encoding**..

I am developing a **PHP Page** that outputs some **latin** (ã, á, à, and so on) **characters**.

When I run the page from my **localhost**, it works just fine. However, when I **upload** it to my test-server and access it via a url, then all latin characters become little squares (in IE by the way).

I've changed the character encoding **on my browser** back and forth to utf8, western european and so on, but none seem to work

Does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either set the `default_charset` in `php.ini` to `UTF-8`, or if you don't have the control over this, add the following line to the top of the PHP file, *before* you emit any character to the response body:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8');
```

#### See also:

- [PHP UTF-8 cheatsheet](http://developer.loftdigital.com/blog/php-utf-8-cheatsheet)

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked for different `default_charset` settings in the php.ini files of your localhost and your test server?

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> // Or actual encoding
</head>
```

Comment: Yeah I will try that as soon as I can edit the code, but even if it wasn't set to utf8 at the start of the html page, it should start working when I, manually, set my browser to read utf8? It still doesn't work.

Comment: If what PHP prints is encoded in utf-8, and you have this tag in HTML, everything should be fine. If these characters come from a database - check if the encoding there is set right.

Comment: I know that. But even if what php outputs **is** utf8 **and** the html content type **isn't** utf8, it should start working when I set my browser to **utf-8**. That should override the content-type tag and display correctly what's written in utf8. My problem is that, **even when** I set my browser to work with utf8 **via right-click** and so on, it **still** doesn't work. And it should.

Comment: Well, IE isn't the most reliable browser ever, just so you know :p

Comment: I know. But what bugs me is that it works when the file is at my localhost. But not when I upload it somewhere else and **then** try to access it.

Comment: The meta header is ignored when the resource is served over HTTP.